# how to get the URL valuel for ajax url and flask?

Tags: ajax, python-3.x, url, flask

I want to get the reser Password token from the displayed URL to display it in ajax url

in python file:

```py
@app.route('/resetRequest', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def resetRequest():
............... # here it generates a token to reset password and send an email to reset the password with the token link.

@app.route('/resetPassword/<token>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def resetPassword(token):
...............
```

After the link displayed link this:

```
http://<domainName>/resetPassword/eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsImlhdCI6MTU2Njg3OTQ0OCwiZXhwIjoxNTY2ODgyNDQ4fQ.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjo0fQ.EedgKKd-WKYWVrSAvLX8lxTdC2AgNqw3QkHDH3j1TzoTa1v8WNIqcZ4YdGwG6MyWuFnQe34A9z4KYQO57cGWBA?
```

I need to get this token:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsImlhdCI6MTU2Njg3OTQ0OCwiZXhwIjoxNTY2ODgyNDQ4fQ.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjo0fQ.EedgKKd-WKYWVrSAvLX8lxTdC2AgNqw3QkHDH3j1TzoTa1v8WNIqcZ4YdGwG6MyWuFnQe34A9z4KYQO57cGWBA?
```

from the URL to display it in ajax url

my ajax

```js
$('#resetTokenForm').on('submit', function(event) {
        // define the url variables
        var url = window.location.href; // not responding
        token = url.split('/').pop(); // not responding

$.ajax({
    data : {
        newPassword: $('#passwordReset').val(),
        confirmNewPassword: $('#confirmPasswordReset').val()
    },
    type : 'POST',
    url : '/resetPassword/'+token
})
```

I tried to get the URL and use `split()` but still doesn't work with me...Is there any way to get the token from URL for ajax url?

Comment: `token = url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;`

Comment: @Kostas Charitidis its not working because var url = window.location.href;  is not responding.

Comment: @Kostas Charitidis done!!, I tried with $(location).attr('pathname'); it works with me...Thanks a lot.